# Php regex with character 'ä'

Tags: php, regex

```
<?
    $s = '';
    $string1 = '<script>';
    $string2 = 'färsk';
    $string3 = 'öde';

    $rex = "/[\^<@\/\{\}\!\*\$%\?=≤>€:\|;#]+/i";
    if (preg_match($rex,$string1)) { $s = NULL; }
    if ($s === NULL) { echo 'null'; } else { echo "not null"; }
?>
```

**Why do $string2 give null**?
What's so special about the 'ä' character? The other Swedish ones, å and ö pass through the regex well.

Appreciate any fix to my regex. I want it to allow everything except the special chars defined in that regex.

EDIT:

---

Clarification:
What I want to do is to let anything but a list of special characters through. $string2 and 3 should both go through, $string 1 shouldn't (because of the < and >).

Comment: how could string2 or 3 ever match? You're not allowing alphabetical characters in the regexs. string only matches because of its  `<` and `>` chars.

Comment: May be http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php#94424 helps you

Comment: @MarcB exactly, I don't want them to match - but $string2 is matching anyways and that is my question. Ä isn't a special character any more than Ö is. I want to let anything through except some special chars like < | [ etc.

Comment: you're not inverting the pattern, because youv'e got `\^` at the start... you've escaped the carat, so it's not a pattern inversion operator anymore. so the regex will literally only match if any of the characters inside the `[...]` are present in the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Avoid unnecessary escaping. See code below:

```
$string1 = '<script>';
$string2 = 'färsk';
$string3 = 'öde';

$rex = "/^[^<>@\/{}!*$%?=≤€:|;#]+$/u";

var_dump (preg_match($rex, $string1)); // false
var_dump (preg_match($rex, $string2)); // true as no special char in character class
var_dump (preg_match($rex, $string3)); // true as no special char in character class
```

Comment: Ah, thanks for cleaning up the regex, but I think you have misunderstood my problem. I want to allow anything except a bunch of special chars like < > { } @ etc. string2 and 3 should both go through, string1 shouldn't.

Comment: Alright check the edited code now, `^` is not supposed to be escaped for negation in character class.

Comment: As I said, $string2 and 3 should both go through. ä isn't a special char any more than ö is - thus my question. $string2 is still false in your example.

Comment: check further edit, you needed `/u` switch for unicode matching.